# How to get on variable a Hubspot firstname field on jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, hubspot

I want to get the HubSpot first name field and store it in the variable is that possible?

I only tried the URL parameter but I can't find it using HubSpot input field.

Answer (score 0):

I already find an answer to this question
https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/Form-onSubmit-send-to-auto-generated-URL-with-form-input/m-p/317429